# Unity Registeration script not working on 000webhost

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created a login and registration on unity using php scripts and my database is mysql. Its working fine when I am using phpmyadmine localhost but as soon as I post my scripts on 000webhost .I am unable to insert data through my registration and my login is working fine . please please HELP

[PHP SCRIPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqUP3.png)

UNTIY CODE

```c#
public class Register : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject loginAs;
    public GameObject username;
    public GameObject email;
    public GameObject password;
    public GameObject confpassword;
    public string CurrentMenu = "Login";
    public GameObject Message;

    private string loginas;
    private string Username;
    private string Email;
    private string Password;
    private string ConfPassword;
    // private string form;
    private bool EmailValid = false;
    private string[] Characters = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i",
                                      "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r",
                                      "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A",
                                  "B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N",
                                  "O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","1",
                                  "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","_","-"};

    private string CreateAccountURL = "https://dbanme.000webhostapp.com/Registeration.php";


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator CreateAccount()
    {
        //This is what sends messages to out php script
        WWWForm Form = new WWWForm();

        //These fields are the variables which we send to out php script
        Form.AddField("loginas", loginas);
        Form.AddField("Username", Username);
        Form.AddField("Email", Email);
        Form.AddField("Password", Password);
        Form.AddField("ConfPassword", ConfPassword);
        WWW CreateAccountWWW = new WWW(CreateAccountURL, Form);
        //Wait for php to send something back to php
        yield return CreateAccountWWW;
        string response = CreateAccountWWW.text;


        if (CreateAccountWWW.error != null)
        {
            string CreateAccountReturn = CreateAccountWWW.text;
            if (response.Contains("failed"))
            {
                Message.GetComponent<Text>().text = response;

                //CurrentMenu = "Login";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Message.GetComponent<Text>().text = response;
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Login");
        }

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
        {
            if (username.GetComponent<InputField>().isFocused)
            {
                email.GetComponent<InputField>().Select();
            }
            if (email.GetComponent<InputField>().isFocused)
            {
                password.GetComponent<InputField>().Select();
            }
            if (password.GetComponent<InputField>().isFocused)
            {
                confpassword.GetComponent<InputField>().Select();
            }

        }

    }

    public void gotologin()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Login");
    }

    //this is the register just telling
    public void ButtonRegister()
    {

        loginas = loginAs.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text;
        if (loginas == "Teacher")
        {
            loginas = "teacher";
            // SceneManager.LoadScene("Login");
        }
        else if (loginas == "Student")
        {
            loginas = "student";
            // SceneManager.LoadScene("Login");
        }


        Username = username.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        Email = email.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        Password = password.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        ConfPassword = confpassword.GetComponent<InputField>().text;


        if (Username != System.String.Empty && Email != System.String.Empty && Password != System.String.Empty && ConfPassword != System.String.Empty)
        {
            emailvalidation();

            //StartCoroutine(CreateAccount());

        }
    }

    void emailvalidation()
    {

        bool SW = false;
        bool EW = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < Characters.Length; j++)
        {
            if (Email.StartsWith(Characters[j]))
            {
                SW = true;
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < Characters.Length; j++)
        {
            if (Email.EndsWith(Characters[j]))
            {
                EW = true;
            }
        }
        if (SW == true && EW == true)
        {

            EmailValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            EmailValid = false;
        }


        bool UN = false;
        bool EM = false;
        bool PW = false;
        bool CPW = false;


        if (Username == "")
        {

            Debug.LogWarning("Username field Empty");
        }
        if (Email != "")
        {
            //emailvalidation();
            if (EmailValid == true)
            {
                if (Email.Contains("@"))
                {
                    if (Email.Contains("."))
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
                        EM = true;
                        SceneManager.LoadScene("Login");
                        StartCoroutine(CreateAccount());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.LogWarning("Email Does not Contain a . sign ");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogWarning("Email does not contain an @ sign");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Email is Incorrect3");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Email field Empty");
        }
        if (Password != "")
        {
            if (Password.Length > 5)
            {
                PW = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Password Must be Atleast 6 Characters long");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Passowrd Field Empty");
        }
        if (ConfPassword != "")
        {
            if (ConfPassword == Password)
            {

                CPW = true;
            }

            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Passwords dont Match");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Confirm Password Field is Empty");
        }
        if (UN == true && EM == true && PW == true && CPW == true)
        {

            bool Clear = true;
            int i = 1;
            foreach (char c in Password)
            {
                if (Clear)
                {
                    Password = "";
                    Clear = false;
                }
                i++;
                char Encrypted = (char)(c * i);
                Password += Encrypted.ToString();
            }


            username.GetComponent<InputField>().text = "";
            email.GetComponent<InputField>().text = "";
            password.GetComponent<InputField>().text = "";
            confpassword.GetComponent<InputField>().text = "";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible help you you without your code. You do have to edit your question and add the C# and php code then tell us what exactly is not working.

Comment: I have just posted my php script and my code
ALL THIS CODE WORKS FINE ON LOCALHOST
It stops inserting details into the database on 000webhost

Comment: Include your PHP code as text, no one is gonna try to read through an image

Comment: The code is fine , it works on localhost normally. I just want to know that why is it not working on 000webhost? My Login file is working but my registeration is . there is no error.

Comment: Use `Debig.Log` to figure out what's failing in your code then tell us. On the php side, you can use `echo` to figure out what's failing. If you can't fix it then you can tell us where it stopped working.

Comment: My code is not failing thats the problem . its a running code but as soon as it goes for hosting it stops working

Comment: have you ever checked `//StartCoroutine(CreateAccount());` part that you commented ?? also there is no Create account coroutine ????

Comment: also one quick tip: you don't need to spell check every single character that user enters, input field in untiy has an option that makes user to just enter the english character + numbers or just email => just check it out under content type in input field